# Is it necessary to have all the types of requests in an app even though only post is being used for that app?

Tags: django

I have an app in django project which is exposed to only post method. I want to know whether it is compulsory to expose this app to other types of requests like get, put, and delete or not.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Seems improbable that a web framework wont handle a the very least GET and POST request, but if it the case, there is no point for you to have GET, PUT and DELETE endpoints indeed.